# Deleting Jenkins jobs through GUI does not delete their workspaces in slaves

Tags: jenkins

I recently deleted 2 job from Jenkins (via GUI). When I log into slaves afterwards I still see workspace of those 2 jobs lying around. Is this behavior normal?

Notes:

- Jenkins master and slaves are all running on Windows environment.
- Master runs on Windows Server 2003 and slaves run on Windows Server 2008 R2.
- Jenkins version is 1.509.2

Regards,
Benil

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately it is: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/SiZ3DL-UJ-8

Workspaces found on slaves are not deleted because this is a non-trivial problem (it would mean that jobs would need to record every slave the job has ever been executed on and it would also have to take into account slaves that are offline, for a real thorough solution).

Comment: You hit bull's eye. Nailed down the question mate. Thanks.

Comment: There's an open issue for Jenkins about this though: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2111

– and a workspace clean-up script was posted to this discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-users/SiZ3DL-UJ-8/Mq1za4sZpwwJ

Answer (score 5):

I have just written a script that can be scheduled periodically to clean unused workspace. It will go through all of the Jenkins slaves and check if the directories under the workspace are already deleted in Jenkins master.

https://gist.github.com/ceilfors/1400fd590632db1f51ca

Comment: Your script did not work for me. It could not find the cloudbees Folder class

Comment: @Adam CloudBees Folder class is available by installing [CloudBees Folder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin). You can sligthly modify the script to remove the Folder support if you don't want to install the plugin.

Comment: @Adam You can make this script work even if you don't have the Cloudbees Folder Plugin, but have it support that plugin if you ever do start to use it, if you change the condition inisFolder() from `return item instanceof Folder` to `return item.class.canonicalName = 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder'`.
You can then remove `import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder`, and you'll no longer _require_ the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To refine what @oblio said

> it would mean that jobs would need to record every slave the job has ever been executed on

*Builds* of jobs do record which slave they ran on, but builds can be (and often are) deleted after a while.

> and it would also have to take into account slaves that are offline

Of course, but this is handled generally by the workspace cleanup feature built into Jenkins core, since it runs as a background process that deals with currently online slaves (deleting seldom-used workspaces), so any slave which is *sometimes* online will eventually be cleaned.

The problem is that this feature currently ignores apparent workspaces that do not correspond to a job which does not exist at the time it runs, to err on the conservative side. [This commit of mine](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/cd526e99e63ae362f2d1ce1a04c3c68a38032a5c#diff-dd3b21aa55f2fc8b02868c404750ddecL107) rewrote the cleanup thread to fix some other problems, but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

I came across an effective script that does a good job of only cleaning when disk space gets low and brings the slave offline: https://gist.github.com/rb2k/8372402

Comment: This script doesn't answer the original question. This script simply deletes all of the jobs found in slaves. Deleting workspaces for existing jobs is bad because it will slow down CI i.e. everything will need to be re-checked out and the space will grow back anyway.

Comment: It's true that it isn't as surgical as it could be. The jobs that still exist will re-grow back, but the deleted jobs will not. Could you maybe update the script such that it checks whether the job is still valid?

Comment: That's what my script in my answer is trying to do. Also the script in your answer will not delete workspace for jobs that have been deleted, hence *everything will re-grow back*. If you read the script, it clearly iterates through the `Jenkins.instance.items` which means the deleted jobs won't be catered for.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't write the script, but it was effective for me. Maybe Jenkins.instance.items works differently than we expect?

Comment: I know it was not written by you, hence I wrote "the script in your answer" :) It's almost impossible for Jenkins.instance.items to return deleted jobs. It was effective for me at first, but it regrows back over time. It's great if it works for you!