# Delete workspace when job is removed by dsl plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using the jenkins dsl plugin to generate jenkins jobs for all branches of a project. When a branch is deleted, the dsl plugin also deletes the respective jenkins jobs.

The problem however is that the workspaces are not deleted together with the jobs, so they clutter up my disk eventually. One solution I've found is to periodically list all workspaces and check whether or not a jenkins job with the same name exists.

I was wondering if there is probably a more elegant solution to automatically remove obsolete workspaces for jenkins jobs that have just been deleted by the dsl plugin.

Comment: What about using [Files.delete()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-) together with [Walking the File Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) from within your DSL code?

Comment: That'd be basically be the same solution, as I'd have to manually compare workspaces and jobs. Running this together with the DSL code has another disadvantage as obsolete jobs are deleted after the DSL script has been executed... So I would not detect them as being deleted. I was thinking about e.g. comparing `DescriptorImpl.getGeneratedJobMap()` with my list of branches, even though it would be much cooler to somehow access the list of deleted jobs directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this was to add another job that runs a Groovy system script that purges all workspaces for jobs that no longer exist or that have been disabled, and have that triggered after the DLS job.

1. Install the [Jenkins Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin)
2. Create a freestyle job
3. Tick the Build Trigger "Build after other projects are built", and set your DSL job as the "Project to watch"
4. Add a "Execute Groovy system script" build step, with the Groovy script as the "Groovy command".

I use the following script, based on [this one](https://gist.github.com/ceilfors/1400fd590632db1f51ca) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32259003/5128343):

```
import hudson.FilePath
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.Job

def deleteUnusedWorkspace(FilePath root, String path) {
  root.list().sort{child->child.name}.each { child ->
    String fullName = path + child.name

    def item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(fullName);

    if (item.class.canonicalName == 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder') {
      deleteUnusedWorkspace(root.child(child.name), "$fullName/")
    } else if (item == null) {
      println "Deleting (no such job): '$fullName'"
      child.deleteRecursive()
    } else if (item instanceof Job && !item.isBuildable()) {
      println "Deleting (job disabled): '$fullName'"
      child.deleteRecursive()
    } else {
      println "Leaving: '$fullName'"
    }
  }
}

for (node in Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
  println "Processing $node.displayName"
  def workspaceRoot = node.rootPath.child("workspace");
  deleteUnusedWorkspace(workspaceRoot, "")
}
```

This does assume that you don't use custom workspaces.

Comment: Thx! I however started to use the Jenkins folder plugin to create a folder for all jobs of one branch. Nice side effect: Deleting a folder automatically deletes respective jobs + workspaces on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on @Jelaby's answer, you can just run it in your script console at: *<jenkins url>/manage/script* for testing and quick modification.

I found that @Jelaby's script did not include the **Jenkins master node** itself when checking for workspaces.
Some small changes I needed for NPEs and to include the master node.
I was running this on Jenkins version: **2.387.1**.

```
import hudson.FilePath
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.Job

def deleteUnusedWorkspace(FilePath root, String path) {
  root.list().sort{child->child.name}.each { child ->
    String fullName = path + child.name

    def item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(fullName);

    if (item?.class?.canonicalName == 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder') {
      deleteUnusedWorkspace(root.child(child.name), "$fullName/")
    } else if (item == null) {
      println "Deleting (no such job): '$fullName'"
      child.deleteRecursive()
    } else if (item instanceof Job && !item.isBuildable()) {
      println "Deleting (job disabled): '$fullName'"
      child.deleteRecursive()
    } else {
      println "Leaving: '$fullName'"
    }
  }
}

jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.computers.each { c ->
    def workspaceRoot = c?.node?.rootPath?.child("workspace");
    if (workspaceRoot) {
      println "Processing node: ${c.node.displayName}, workspace: ${workspaceRoot}"
      deleteUnusedWorkspace(workspaceRoot, "")
    } else {
       println "Could not get workspace for: ${c.node.displayName}!"
    }
}
```